# Histogram equalization

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, normal-distribution, normalization, histogram

I'm trying to equalize the following histogram:
[image]

I tried histogram equalization, but that didn't seem to work the way I wanted. I got something likes this:
[image]

Which is equally distributed everywhere. What I was hoping to get when using histogram equalization, was a symmetric distribution that has the following shape as indicated by the black curve.
[image]

Does anyone have an idea of how that can be done or what methods can be used to achieve this?

I used matlab to equalize the data with the following code:
[image]

Kind regards,

Comment: Since you were able to "equalize" your data to a uniform histogram, I'm sure you could do the same to your targeted distribution, too.  So, all you need to do is equalize your data *and then apply the inverse of the other equalization.*

Comment: I added the matlab code I am using to equalize the histograms to my question above.
How would I go about taking the inverse of that?

Comment: Use the [ECDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ecdf+-multivariate+-confidence+score%3A1).